# Ошибка ajax: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

JS:

```
var usernameStatic = $('#username').val();


$('#save').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = $('#username');
    console.log('/' + usernameStatic); // /Tracey
    $.ajax({
        url: '/' + usernameStatic,
        method: 'PUT',
        data: {
            username: username
        }
    });
});

jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

HTML:

```
document
    html(lang='en')
        head
            title= "Users"
        body
            h1= user.username
            h2= 'id: ' + user.user_id
            img(src=user.avatar)
            h2 EDIT
            form
                input(value= user.username, id= 'username')
                button(id= 'save') Save
            script(src= 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js')
            script(src= '/js/user.js')
```

В чем ошибка ?

Answer (score 4):

```
data: {
            username: username
        }
```

на

```
data: {
            username: username.val()
        }
```